# Clip layer with selected object from another layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, arcmap, editing, clip

In ArcMap, I can clip a layer with selected objects from another layer by using the editor toolbar.

[image: ArcMap clip tool]

I want to do the same operation in QGIS. I want to create holes in the landuse layer by selecting objects from the lake layer. Is it possible?

I can't find a similar option in QGIS 2.8.1.

Answer (score 2):

Well if you are still interested this is a very interesting link to a blog post where it compares how things are done in QGIS versus ArcGIS

http://www.northrivergeographic.com/archives/clipping-in-arcgis-and-clipping-in-qgis

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should be able to select which features you want to use for both layers (I'm using QGIS 2.6.1):

[image: Clip option]

[image: Clip]

Hope this helps!

Comment: It works but i dont want to create new shape layer. I work with postGIS. In ArcGis you can clip object during edit session without geoprocessing tools, just by selecting object and clipping it.

Comment: Here is a detailed blog post you may find interesting comparing QGIS and ARCGIS clipping http://www.northrivergeographic.com/archives/clipping-in-arcgis-and-clipping-in-qgis

Comment: @AntonioLocandro - That's a great link, you should post it as an **answer** and include a basic description on how to achieve it.

Comment: @AntonioLocandro - Post your answer buddy, I will upvote it :)