# How to clip a points layer using a polygon/defined borders?

Tags: qgis, point, clip

[image]I have a global ocean temperature point data downloaded from NOAA.

I want to clip and isolate data just for Southeast Asia in the form of a rectangle.

I would also want to do this to other parameters such as salinity, phosphate, etc, so I would need to know the boundaries to be used for clipping the other parameters.

Comment: Have you checked this answer : http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/143970/clip-layer-with-selected-object-from-another-layer-in-qgis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the **Vector-> Research Tools -> Select By Location**

[image]

The Parameters are:

- Select Features in: "Your point file"
- That intersect Features in: "YOUR RECTANGLE"

Then once that selection is made **Save the new selection as a shapefile** by right clicking the point file in the table of contents -> Save As:

[image]

Make sure to check the Save Only Selected, this will make a new shapefile from the Selected points within the rectangle.

For the other parameters you can use the **Select By Expression** *here is a turorial:* [Here](http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/working_with_attributes.html) as opposed to **SELECT BY LOCATION**

You can use PyQGIS to automate the process

Comment: Note I just saw you are using QGIS let me edit!

Comment: Thanks a lot. How long should this go? It seems mine is taking too long. I've been runnning it for more than 5mins already.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a geoprocessing tool called **Clip**. You can find in **QGIS** in **Vector > Geoprocessing Tools > Clip**.

The detailed description for geoprocessing tools can be found here: http://grindgis.com/software/qgis/basic-editing-tools-in-qgis.